# the following inequality is true，but I can't prove it

Tags: inequalities, induction, pr.probability, co.combinatorics

The inequality is
\begin{equation*} 
\sum_{k=1}^{2d}\left(1-\frac{1}{2d+2-k}\right)\frac{d^k}{k!}>e^d\left(1-\frac{1}{d}\right)
\end{equation*}
for all integer $d\geq 1$. I use computer to verify it for $d\leq 50$, and find it is true, but I can't prove it.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: How did this arise? How do you know it's true?

Comment: Would you like to give us some background and motivation, as per http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask...

Comment: For that matter, what does "small $d$" mean? $d<10$? $d<10^{10}$?

Comment: @Andres: I think the solution at SE is incorrect.

Comment: Have you tried the Abel transform http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts ?

Comment: @math67: the link provideed by Mark is certainly more detailled on such a topic than any explanation that is suitable here. Did you read it?

Comment: @Benoit: I have read it. But it seems useless for this proof.

Comment: I also don't think it is research level. I would try to pair up the terms on the LHS as k and (2d+1-k) and show that the latter is always bigger, then use the series expansion of e^d.

Comment: @domotorp Why don’t you think it is research level? He did some research and got stuck at some ugly inequality. Not everybody is like Ramanujan and the inequality is definitely non-trivial.

Comment: @domotorp I don't understand your method. Could you give a detailed explain?

Comment: domotrop, have you actually tried this? There are a lot of error terms to keep track of, and most people never take a course that covers this sort of manipulation. Voting to reopen.

Comment: The inequality seems nice; I think the Q shd. remain open (voted).

Comment: Before voting to reopen, I would like to see the OP give some motivation.

Comment: I cast the final vote to reopen. The question is well-posed, not hopeless, and I cannot do it in 10 minutes, so, I guess, it can stay if not based on definitions, then based on precedents.

Comment: I just slogged through the Stirling's formula, Euler-Maclaurin approach and I got that the sum is $e^d (1-1/d+O(1/d^2)$ (in other words, inconclusive), after a ton of cancellation which required, among other things, knowing the $1/(12 n)$ term in Stirling's formula. I take this as evidence that this inequality is very tight, and probably not easy to prove by.

Comment: I've put my progress up at math.SE. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/414027/448

Comment: Phew, then I shouldn't feel so bad; I tried for 10 minutes too and could not prove it---but if fedja himself could not do it in 10 minutes, then this inequality deserves to stay open! I agree with David, it seems quite tight.

Comment: Let $D(d)$ be $e^{-d} d^2$ times the difference between the two sides.
Then $D(100) = 0.9795408\ldots$, $D(1000) = 0.99799594738\ldots$,
and $D(10^4) = 0.999799959947939\ldots$, suggesting that in general 
$D(d) = 1 - 2/d + 4/d^2 + O(d^{-3})$.  This in turn suggests that taking
David's math.SE analysis one step further will give a proof
(modulo finite computation to deal with small $d$).


Comment: Um, make the $1/d^2$ coefficient $-4$, not $+4$.  The analysis I give below
confirms.

Comment: (I've deleted an obsolete comment above. The link to the math.SE version is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/413558/462)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[**Edited** *mostly to fix a typo noted by David Speyer*]

The following analysis simplifies and completes the
"routine but somewhat unpleasant" task of
recovering the actual inequality from the asymptotic analysis.

The idea is that once we've obtained the asymptotic expansion
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2d} \left( 1 - \frac1{2d+2-k} \right) \frac{d^k}{k!}
\sim e^d \left( 1 - \frac1{d} + \frac1{d^2} - \frac2{d^3} \cdots \right)
$$
by expanding $1 - 1/(2d+2-k)$ in a power series about $k=d$,
we should be able to replace $1 - 1/(2d+2-k)$ by something smaller
that can be summed exactly and is close enough that the result
is within a small enough multiple of $e^d$ to maintain the
desired inequality.

Because it takes about $2m$ terms of the power series in $k$
to get within $O(1/d^m)$, I had to match the power series to within $O(k-d)^6$.
Let
$$
A_6(k) =
\frac{d+1}{d+2}
- \frac{k-d}{(d+2)^2}
- \frac{(k-d)^2}{(d+2)^3}
- \frac{(k-d)^3}{(d+2)^4}
- \frac{(k-d)^4}{(d+2)^5}
- \frac{(k-d)^5}{(d+2)^6}
- \frac{(k-d)^6}{2(d+2)^6},
$$
so the final term has denominator $2(d+2)^6$ instead of $(d+2)^7$.
Then
$$
1 - \frac1{2d+2-k}
 = A_6(k) + \frac{(k-d)^6(2d-k)}{2(d+2)^6(2d+2-k)} \geq A_6(k)
$$
for all $k \leq 2d$.  Hence
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2d} \left( 1 - \frac1{2d+2-k} \right) \frac{d^k}{k!} >
\sum_{k=1}^{2d} A_6(k) \frac{d^k}{k!}.
$$
On the other hand, since $A_6(k)$ is a polynomial in $k$,
the power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty A_6(k) d^k/k!$ is elementary
(see my earlier answer for the explanation; David Speyer implicitly
used this too in the calculation "with the aid of *Mathematica*").
I find
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty A_6(k) \frac{d^k}{k!}
= \frac{2d^6 + 22d^5 + 98d^4 + 102d^3 + 229d^2 + 193d + 64}{2(d+2)^6} e^d
$$ $$
= \left(
 1 - \frac1d + \frac{2d^5 + 5d^4 + 69d^3 + 289d^2 + 320d + 128}{2d(d+2)^6}
\right) \cdot e^d > \left(1 - \frac1d\right) e^d.
$$
We're not quite finished, because we need a lower bound on
$\sum_{k=1}^{2d} A_6(k) d^k/k!$, not $\sum_{k=0}^\infty$.
However, once $d$ is at all large the terms with $k=0$ and $k>2d$
are negligible compared with our lower bound
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty A_6(k) d^k/k! - \left(1 - \frac1d\right) e^d
\geq \frac{2d^5 + 5d^4 + 69d^3 + 289d^2 + 320d + 128}{2d(d+2)^6} e^d >
\frac{d^4}{(d+2)^6} e^d.
$$
Indeed the $k=0$ term is less than $1$, and for $k>2d$ we have
$A_6(k) < A_6(2d) = 1/2$ while $d^k/k!$ is exponentially smaller than $e^d$:
$$
\sum_{k=2d+1}^\infty \frac{d^k}{k!} <
 2^{-2d} \sum_{k=2d+1}^\infty \frac{(2d)^k}{k!} <
 2^{-2d} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2d)^k}{k!} = (e/2)^{2d}.
$$
So we're done once
$$
1 + \frac12 \left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^{2d} < \frac{d^4}{(d+2)^6} e^d,
$$
which happens once $d \geq 14$.  Since the desired inequality
has already been verified numerically up to $d=50$, we're done. **QED**

Comment: Wow. Very impressive.          

Comment: ++++1: wow! as usual, it is a pleasure to see Noam's solutions!

Comment: This is a very slick trick. In the penultimate displayed equation, I think some $k$'s and $d$'s are switched (you want to sum on $k$, yes?)

Comment: Thanks to all!  David Speyer is right; I've now edited my answer
to fix that error.


Comment: Beautiful proof, Noam. Could you please explicate your comment "because it takes about $2m$ terms of the power series in $k$ to get within $O(1/dm)$"? Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

This is true for large $d$, and probably for all $d$. I'll prove that the sum is 
$$e^d(1-1/d+1/d^2+O(1/d^{2.5+\epsilon}))$$
and leave the explicit bounds to you.

Set $k=d+\ell$. For $|\ell| \leq d^{0.5+\epsilon}$, we have
$$1-1/(2d+2-k) = 1-\frac{1}{d} \frac{1}{1-(\ell-2)/d} = 1-\frac{1}{d} - \frac{\ell-2}{d^2} - \frac{(\ell-2)^2}{d^3} + O(d^{-2.5+3 \epsilon})$$
$$=1-\frac{1}{d} - \frac{\ell}{d^2} + \frac{2 d - \ell^2}{d^3} + O(d^{-2.5+\epsilon}).$$

We will show later that the difference between your sum and 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{d^k}{k!} \left( 1-\frac{1}{d} - \frac{\ell}{d^2} + \frac{2 d - \ell^2}{d^3}  \right)$$
is very small, where $\ell = k-d$. Assuming that, let's compute the new sum. With the aid of *Mathematica*, 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} \left( 1-\frac{1}{d} - \frac{k-d}{d^2} + \frac{2 d - (k-d)^2}{d^3}  \right) = e^x \left( 1-\frac{1}{d}+\frac{x}{d^2}-\frac{x^2}{d^3} + \frac{2}{d^2} - \frac{x}{d^3} \right). $$

Plugging in $x=d$, 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{d^k}{k!} \left( 1-\frac{1}{d} - \frac{k-d}{d^2} + \frac{2 d - (k-d)^2}{d^3}  \right) = e^d \left( 1-\frac{1}{d} + \frac{1}{d^2} \right).$$
The error coming from $O(d^{-2.5+\epsilon}) \sum d^k/k!$ is $e^d O(d^{-2.5+\epsilon})$.

We now just need to think about the error coming from discarding the terms with $|\ell|>d^{0.5+\epsilon}$. No matter what $\ell$ is, that error is no worse than $d^k/k! \cdot ( O(\ell^2/d^3) + O(1))$. But, for $|\ell| > d^{0.5 + \epsilon}$, we have $d^k/k! \leq e^{-d^{2 \epsilon}}$ as I pointed out on math.SE, so the contribution from these terms is exponentially small.

I have not found a slick way to give a proof for all $d$, rather than an asymptotic result.

Comment: Maybe we could try to prove that if the inequality holds true for a given large $d$, it still holds true for $d-1$? This would settle the problem for all $d$.

Comment: I also thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 14):

[I think the following comes down to basically what David Speyer is doing,
systematized to get as much of the asymptotic expansion as we want.]

For large $d$ there's an asymptotic expansion
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2d} \left( 1 - \frac1{2d+2-k} \right) \frac{d^k}{k!}
= e^d \left( 1 - \frac1d + \frac1{d^2} - \frac2{d^3} - \frac4{d^4}
 - \frac{52}{d^5} - \frac{608}{d^6} \cdots
\right)\phantom..
$$
It should be routine but somewhat unpleasant to get error estimates
for the expansion through $1/d^2$
sufficient to prove the desired inequality for all $d$
(given that it is known to be true up to $d=50$ by numerical computation).

To obtain $m$ terms of this asymptotic expansion, we need about $2m$ terms
of the Taylor expansion of $1 - 1/(2d+2-k)$ about $k=d$, which is the peak
of $d^k/k!$.  This Taylor expansion is a constant minus a geometric series:
$$
1 - \frac1{2d+2-k} = \frac{d+1}{d+2}
- \frac{k-d}{(d+2)^2} - \frac{(k-d)^2}{(d+2)^3} - \frac{(k-d)^3}{(d+2)^4}
- \cdots .
$$
Now when we truncate this expansion before the $O((k-d)^N)$ term
we get $(d+2)^{-N}$ times a polynomial in $d$ and $k$.   We can then
write that polynomial as a finite sum
$$
P_0(d) + k P_1(d) + k(k-1) P_2(d) + k(k-1)(k-2) P_3(d) + \cdots
$$
and then multiplying each term $k! P_i(d) / (k-i)!$ by $d^k/k!$
and summing over $k \geq 0$ we get $P_i(d) d^i e^d$.  Hence our $N$-th
approximation is $\sum_i P_i(d) d^i e^d \left/ (d+2)^N \right.$,
which is $e^d$ times some rational function in $d$.
Expanding this rational function about $d = \infty$
we obtain the above power series once $N \geq 11$.

[The next few coefficients past $-608$ are
$$
-8864, -151408, -1973184, -65998976, -1633489408, -44681812096, -1336497292288;
$$
no, this sequence is not in the OEIS.]